# How to know find DocumentComplete and BeforeNavigate2 event for the entire document?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, bho, ieaddon

I am learning to write a BHO in c#, and i have written event handlers for DocumentComplete and BeforeNavigate2. During debugging i notice that they are triggered multiple times for certain webpages like yahoo.co.in.

I understand that this could be because of presence of multiple frames in the page. 
My questions are:-

1. How do i know which is the event for the complete page being loaded?
2. How do i know which is the event which gets triggered when we are about to navigate away from the page?

Adding Some Sample Code

```
private InternetExplorer iExplorer;
int IObjectWithSite.SetSite(object pUnkSite)
{
    if (pUnkSite != null)
    {
        ieInstance = (InternetExplorer)pUnkSite;
        // Register the DocumentComplete event.
        ieInstance.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(ieInstance_DocumentComplete);
        ieInstance.BeforeNavigate2 += new DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(ieInstance_BeforeNavigate2);
    }
    return 0;
}

private void ieInstance_BeforeNavigate2(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object Flags, ref object TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, ref object Headers, ref bool Cancel)
{
}

private void ieInstance_DocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
{
}
```

Comment: 1 (and maybe 2) sounds like it's answered by this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8359461/593627

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett, the part of it about `_pUnkSite` is wrong. The site object doesn't refer to the top browser object.

Comment: @Noseratio: Ok, thanks for the correction. To be honest I am not familiar with the subject, I just found the answer (that was accepted) and assumed it was correct (without looking at the comments).

Comment: Yes, DocumentComplete fires for every frame in the web page.  Which is why it has a URL argument, you can use that and compare it with the URL that you originally navigated, that one will be last.  Counting off the frames is another way.  Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3239313/17034).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `pDisp` parameter of the `BeforeNavigate2` and `DocumentComplete` event handlers, it refers to the instance of the `SHDocVw.WebBrowser` object corresponding to the frame (or the top browser):

```
static bool IsTop(object pDisp)
{
    var thisBrowser = pDisp as SHDocVw.WebBrowser;
    var parent = thisBrowser .Parent as SHDocVw.WebBrowser;
    return (parent == thisBrowser || parent == null);
}
```